# SD-Card-> Missing value

Tags: android, bluetooth, filestream

Really need some help.
For already one week I'am trying to save (raw-)data(-bytes) correctly to my SD-card of a Android Phone.

The mobile get the data via Bluetooth from a microcontroller. The data is printed out correctly by a Terminal, so obviously the Java-Code is incorrect.

For testing this, a variable (8bit) is incrementing and after this step the value of the variable is sending to the phone. 
When I read out the created file with a hex-view, there are a lot of zeros between the guilty values ( In case: µC is not sending anything) and for some reason there are a lot of Values missing / maybe even the Chronology is wrong.

The saving part:

```
h=new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage (android.os.Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            String path = "/sdcard/" + dateipfad.getText().toString() + ".txt";
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

            try {
                File myFile = new File(path);
                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile,true);

                fOut.write(readBuf);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            break;
        }
    }
};
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You're not extracting the data out of the message.
`msg.getData.getByteArray("keyOfTheMessage")`;

Comment: thank you for your reply.

Are you sure, that's the problem?

I mean is it not enough to create a Filestream like this:



                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                            fOut.write(readBuf);
                            fOut.flush();
                            fOut.close();



If not, can you pls explain why not and how to do this correct,I programm with Android Studio, I'am very new to this IDE and to JAVA. And how to paste your line of code in mine? -> keyOfMessage?

Comment: What is sending the message to your handler?

Comment: µc via Bluetooth (class:2.0). BLE: HC06 (Uart). 

Maybe that's the same problem: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157297/android-bluetooth-adapter-message-handler-buffer-limit

?

Comment: Just read this info: 

The Maximum Transmission Unit in BLE/GATT is 20 bytes. 

So, I only can receive 20 Bytes  and have to splitt my "Stream"? Is this correct? To understand what I'am doing wrong would help me a lot.